# No route matches [POST] "/users"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api, routes

I'm new to rails, and I'm trying to build API following Code School tutorial.
I get this error while trying to post to '/users' path.

routes file code :

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  namespace :api,constraints: {subdomain: 'api'}, path: '/' do
   resources :users, except: :delete
  end
end
```

and the test code is :

```
require 'test_helper'
class CreatingUsersTest < ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest
  test 'create users' do
   post api_users_path,
      {user: {name: 'test', email:'test@test.com'}}.to_json,
      {'Accept' => Mime::JSON, 'Content-Type': Mime::JSON.to_s}
   assert_equal response.status, 201
   assert_equal response.content_type, Mime::JSON
   user = json(response.body)
   assert_equal api_user_url(user[:id]), response.location
 end
end
```

And when I use rake routes :

```
    api_users GET /users(.:format) api/users#index {:subdomain=>"api"}
              POST   /users(.:format) api/users#create {:subdomain=>"api"}
    ....
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the route you constraint the subdomain to be `api`

```
namespace :api,constraints: {subdomain: 'api'}, path: '/' do
```

but then in the test you call `api_user_path`

```
post api_users_path
```

that uses a generic hostname (`test.host`), and not the `api` hostname. The solution is to pass a specific host to the helper that satisfies the requirement.

```
post api_users_path(host: "api.test.host")
```